# Farming out subprocess jobs

Tags: python, subprocess, environment, dask-distributed

I have got a single dask distributed script that reads a list of hosts from a file and deploys an SSH cluster for me (so far so good). I don't use the `dask-worker` command line tool as I would like everything to launch from one parent python script. I would like to use the cluster thus set up to run various jobs using `subprocess.run` or something similar on the worker nodes.

The processes that I want to run are python jobs that need to be started in an appropriate conda environment. This is where I come unstuck: attempting to activate a conda environment gets me `Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.` in `stderr`.

I'm using `subprocess.run` with `shell=True`. Given that my normal shell is set up to use conda, I was slightly surprised by the error.

The dask distributed workers seem to have a very limited environment (my `.bashrc` isn't loaded) and I don't seem to be able to even source files to try to add to the environment. I have no problem activating the relevant conda env if I use a non-distributed set-up (`distributed.Client()`), so I guess it is something to do with the way that the dask distributed remote worker environment works. I know that conda and the relevant environments are available on the remote nodes (they all mount the same file system).

So, is there an easy way to say to a dask distributed remote worker: "launch this python script using this conda environment", preferably using `subprocess.run`?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a `bash` usage issue rather than anything to do with `dask`.

If we force `bash` to be interactive then we get the environment we expect and can run the jobs. I looked for a more elegant solution, but you quickly get bogged down in the details of what your distribution thinks it should use as the shell environment for login vs non-login shells, interactive vs non-interactive etc etc.